# insertion sort code recheck

Tags: java, insertion-sort

This is my insertion sort code. This code works but is this the way to write an insertion sort? I looked few tutorials but they do it in a different way.

```
int thirdArray[] = { 0, 22, 1, 10, 8, 5,39 };
for (int i = 0; i < thirdArray.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j > 0; j--) {
        if (thirdArray[j] < thirdArray[j - 1]) {
            int index = thirdArray[j];
            thirdArray[j] = thirdArray[j - 1];
            thirdArray[j - 1] = index;
        }
    }
}
for (int number : thirdArray) {
    System.out.print(number + "\t");
}
```

Comment: If this code works then this question is probably more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GBlodgett Thank you so much. I'll post it there.

Comment: Your insertion sort is missing a break condition for the inner loop. Remember that insertion sort has a best case time complexity of *O(n)*. Minor optimization: you can print an array through `import java.util.Arrays; ... System.out.println(Arrays.toString(thirdArray));`

Comment: @Turing85 So after the if statement adding a else { break; } statement would work? Sorry I am little bit confused about the break condition.

Comment: @user508030 Yes. But first convince yourself why the `break;` is rectified.

Answer (score 0):

With Java 7 its so simple to do sorting now days.

```
  Arrays.sort(thirdArray);
```

This would sort the elements of the array sorted.

Comment: OP did not ask how to sort an array, but if the given code is a realization of the insertion sort algorithm. You did not answer the quetsion.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are taking extra space for the swap operation. However, It's a valid approach, but you can optmize it in the following way

```
    int thirdArray[] = { 0, 22, 1, 10, 8, 5,39 };
    int key,j;
    for(int i = 1 ; i < thirdArray.length ; i++)
    {
        key = thirdArray[i];
        j = i - 1;

        while(j >=0 && key < thirdArray[j])
        {
            thirdArray[j+1] = thirdArray[j];
            j--;
        }
        arr[j+1] = key;
    }
}
```

In the above code, you start comparing from the first index with it's previous, if it's smaller, overwrite it's values (you are already saving the current value in key) in the end place it in it's correct position. We can guarantee that after the sorting that all the element on the left are sorted. Insertion sort has Worst-case performance: О(n^2) Best-case performance: O(n). By swapping we are adding more complexity which you can avoid it.